# Posting with ajax code

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to post some data. According to this posted datas i am checking something and doing an action accordingly. So i have problem with this below code.

why this script does not work?

```
<script>
function control(adiv,ido,idt,bu) {
    var resultdiv=adiv;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "main.php",
        data: { adiv: adiv, one: ido, two: idt, three: bu }
    }).done(function( msg ) {
        $('#'+resultdiv).html( msg );
    });

}
</script>
```

Comment: *What* is not working correctly?

Comment: This piece of script is fine, maybe your problem is somewhere else!

Comment: Please show how are you calling your function

Answer (score 0):

Jquery ajax requests have the "success" and "error" function callbacks, try to use these

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "main.php",
  data: { adiv: adiv, one: ido, two: idt, three: bu }
  success: function(data) {
      $('#'+resultdiv).html( msg );
  });
```

See here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Check also if you didn't forgot to include jquery scripts in your page

```
<script src="http//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a simple ajax post, try $.post:

```
$.post( "main.php",
{
adiv: adiv, one: ido, two: idt, three: bu
},
function (data, status) {
$('#'+resultdiv).html( data );
});
```